# Detecting touch on the entire screen

Tags: iphone, uigesturerecognizer, uitouch

I have a number of UIViews with GestureRecognizers attached.

My issue is I want the user to be able to touch the screen and drag their finger and I want to track their finger location.

How is this done so that the gesturerecognizers dont get triggered, but that if the users finger starts to move along the screen it gets tracked.

Thanks

Comment: watch wwdc 2011 session video 118 if you can

Comment: How is this done so that the gesturerecognizers dont get triggered, but that if the users finger starts to move along the screen it gets tracked.

that's too vague

Comment: I want to have the screen detect a finger moving around on the screen without triggering the current GestureRecognizers that are attached to UIviews within the main screen. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can handle currently recognized guestures through

```
    -(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
     shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
```

This method will tell you what two gestures it found at the same time, so you can make choice to choose one over the other. In another words, you can tell that your finger tracking is what you want to recognize in stead of swipe.

Comment: Thanks. But the issue is, without the finger moving on screen, how could the priority be given over the gesture recognizer on a small UIView. if a small UIView with its own recognizer is touched first, but the user starts moving their finger, then I need to start tracking the touch.but how would I know that it wasnt just a touch on the UIView and not that the user is going to start moving their finger around?